# pymongo: how to access MongoDB collection by name as string?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, selenium-chromedriver

I want to write csv files into mongoDB.

I want to name the collection same as the csv file name.

Below is the code that i have tried. This writes the collection name as "collection".

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import os

#get all csv files from the directory
dir_path = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\project'
output_files = [file for file in os.listdir(dir_path) if file.endswith(".csv")]

client = MongoClient()
db = client.senci

for file in output_files:
     collection = file[-4]
     df = pd.read_csv(file) 
     records_ = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')    
     result = db.collection.insert_many(records_ )
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [db.getCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/):

```py
db.get_collection(collection).insert_many(records_ )
```

from the docs:

> Returns a collection or a view object that is functionally equivalent to using the `db.<collectionName>`

Comment: I am getting this error when i use db.get_collection(): TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list.

Comment: yup, one of my csv is empty. But i have another error after correcting it: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 10: invalid start byte

Comment: @Gokva: those errors have nothing to do with the original question, do they?

Comment: fixed by changing:df = pd.read_csv(file) to df = pd.read_csv(file, engine='python) .